# I have dvd writer speed at 2.4x but no dvd is burning?

Tags: dvd-burning, nero

I have dvd writer speed at 2.4x but no dvd is writing? I am trying to write a moserbaer 8x DVD(8.5 GB) using various writing software (Nero 8, Cyberlink Power2GO) but i am keep getting error message **Burn process failed at 2.4x (3324 kb/s)**

I am not able to understand the issue, please let me know, how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We Need to know more info - Can you try using a different speed to burn the disk? Try keeping it at default speed.   has it ever worked? if so - what has changed since it worked? That is likely your issue.even though you likely can't recall exactly what has changed.  ALso, have you tried a slightly smaller file if possible?   time the lead in and FAT is written maybe it's too much data.  Tried a different Program or type of Disk?

Comment: FYI, this should be a comment.